# Regex to extract similar config blocks throughout ini file

Tags: regex

I want to extract the hostname and node id values from the [ndb_mgmd] blocks **only**, from the mysql ini config file. There are other blocks in the file which are not needed.

1. Is it possible to extract just the hostname and node id values from all the [ndb_mgmd] blocks?
2. Otherwise, how can I extract those whole blocks using regex (without the [ndb_mgmd] headers preferably)?

Config file example below.

```
Random unwanted text in config file

[unwanted_block]
hostname=0.0.0.0
NodeId=2

[ndb_mgmd]
hostname=2.2.2.2
NodeId=1

[mysql_unwanted]
hostname=3.3.3.3
NodeId=6

[ndb_mgmd]
hostname=2.2.2.2
NodeId=4

randomconfig
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've played around and the following regex seems to work in playground (may not be the most ideal solution), however it's not working in ServiceNow where I'm trying to use.

`/^\[ndb_mgmd\][\r\n]?hostname=(.*)[\r\n]?NodeId=(.*)/gm`

Answer (score 0):

You can extract what you need with capture groups:

Hostnames: `^hostname=(\d\.\d\.\d\.\d)$`
NodeIds: `^NodeId=(\d)$`

Comment: Thanks, however, this fetches all the hostnames. The part I'm struggling with is I'm only interested in the hostsnames under [ndb_mgmd] block